# The indent of “if-else-end if;” work weirdly in vim

Tags: vim, vhdl, neovim

When I edit a vhdl file using vim or neovim, the “if-else-end if;” statement never autoindent properly. When I typed “if xxx then” and Enter, it looks like as follows:

```
if xxx then
    |
```

which is fine.
Then I keep typing “end” and a Space, the it looks like:

```
if xxx then

end |
```

After I finish the statement by typing “if;”, then it looks like follows:

```
if xxx then

    end if;
```

So, how can I fix this?

The filetype is **vhdl**, the vim version is **8.2**, and the script loaded by vim that implements vhdl indention is **/usr/share/vim/vim82/indent/vhdl.vim**.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue... What does `:set ft?` return while you're editing a VHDL file, does it tell you `filetype=vhdl` or something different? What version of Vim do you have installed? Perhaps [edit] the question to include output of `:version` and possibly `:scriptnames` which shows which scripts were loaded by Vim (one of which would implement VHDL indentation...)

Comment: Same problem here with MavVim 8.2.3455 under macOS and the standard `indent.vim`. Same problem also with vim 8.2 under Debian 11.1, again with the standard `indent.vim`. This also happens with an empty `entity` declaration: the closing `end` is indented while it should not.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce this with a vhdl filetype, using filetype indentation.

```
:set filetype?    --> vhdl
:filetype         --> filetype detection:ON plugin:ON indent:ON
```

I noticed that the error described is only happening when there were no non-comment, non-empty lines between the `if` and `end if;` lines:

```
if xxx then
    SOMETHING <= '1';
end if;

if xxx then
    end if;
```

The error is caused by this part of the $VIMRUNTIME/indent/vhdl.vim file.  If the current string contains `end if` **and** the previous line's string contains `if`, then return the number `ind`.

```
  " indent:   -sw
  " keywords: "else", "elsif", "end" + "block", "for", "function", "generate", "if", "loop", "procedure", "process", "record", "units"
  " where:    start of current line
  let s5 = 'block\|for\|function\|generate\|if\|loop\|procedure\|process\|record\|units'
  if curs =~? '^\s*\%(else\|elsif\|end\s\+\%('.s5.'\)\)\>'
    if prevs =~? '^\s*\%(elsif\|'.s5.'\)'
      return ind
    else
      return ind - shiftwidth()
    endif
  endif
```

Earlier in the script, the value of `ind` is increased by a shiftwidth() if the previous line contains `then`.   Later in the script, the value of `ind` is decreased by a shiftwidth() is `end`  matches the current line.  This is the intended behavior, but the above `return ind` prevents that from happening.

**Solution**
Comment out the `return ind` line.

```
  " indent:   -sw
  " keywords: "else", "elsif", "end" + "block", "for", "function", "generate", "if", "loop", "procedure", "process", "record", "units"
  " where:    start of current line
  let s5 = 'block\|for\|function\|generate\|if\|loop\|procedure\|process\|record\|units'
  if curs =~? '^\s*\%(else\|elsif\|end\s\+\%('.s5.'\)\)\>'
    if prevs =~? '^\s*\%(elsif\|'.s5.'\)'
      " DO NOTHING.  COMMENT OUT LINE BELOW
      " return ind
    else
      return ind - shiftwidth()
    endif
  endif
```

If you can't edit your $VIMRUNTIME/indent/vhdl.vim file, you'll need to copy it to ~/.vim/indent/vhdl.vim first.   When you restart Vim with a vhdl file, it will use your local override.

Please also report this as an issue at https://github.com/vim/vim

Comment: You are right that the problem won’t show up if if I type the “if-end if” statement line by line, which makes no empty line behind the “if xxx then” line when I type “end if”. It’s my habit to close the “if” statement as soon as I have typed “if xxx then”, then I encountered this problem. Your solution works if there is only one condition branch. But if I add a “else” branch, problem still exists.

Comment: oops, I didn't test with an "else" branch too.  Are you able to understand the indent/vhdl.vim file enough to proceed?   It's a pretty gnarly indent script compared with some other ones in $VIMRUNTIME/indent.

Comment: I’m not familiar with the vim script language yet. I’ll spend some time on it later. Thanks

Comment: In Vim indent scripts, there are some keys things you need to know:
    `set indentkeys` defines characters, that when typed in insert mode, will trigger the `indentexpr`.   Indentation with the `=` and a motion will also trigger `indentexpr`.

In this script, the function that acts as the `indentexpr` will return an integer which is the number of spaces the line should be indented.   

The function `indent()` returns the number of spaces a line is currently indented.

The function `shiftwidth()` returns the `'shiftwidth'` setting.

Comment: In general, an indentexpr function will get the line's current indent() value and then use context conditions to either add or subtract a shiftwidth() quantity to the current indentation.